# Algoritmo para validar si un sudoku es correcto

Tags: python-3.x, string, lista

estoy tratando de construir un algoritmo que pueda verificar si un sudoku, el cuál ya tiene valores, es correcto o no.

El sudoku se guarda en una lista de 9 elementos, que a su vez cada elemento es otra lista de 9 elementos. Escribí una función para evaluar cada línea y cada columna, sin embargo me falta evaluar cada cuadrante de 3x3.

Con esta función puedo evaluar apenas el primer cuadrante pero no encuentro la forma para evaluar los demás, ¿alguna idea?

```
def sudokuSqr():
    sqr = ''
    a = 0
    i = 0
    for n in range(9): # Debería recorrer los 9 cuadrantes
        for a in range (3): # Recorre el cuadrante y forma una cadena con los valores
            ln = "".join(lst[a][i] for i in range(3))
            sqr += ln
        for x in sqr: # Revisa si cada valor se repite más de una vez en la cadena
            if sqr.count(x) > 1:
                print("No")
                return
            else:
                sqr = ''
                continue
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Representamos el sudoku como una lista, donde cada elemento contiene otra lista, con los dígitos de la fila respectiva.

La función `extraer_caja` recibe esta lista y el número de caja (0 a 8) que se desea extraer, retornando una lista con los 9 dígitos de esa caja.

```
def extraer_caja(sudoku, numero):
    """
    Extrae la caja y la convierte en lista
    :param sudoku: La matriz (lista de listas)
    :param numero: 0, 1, 2, ... 8, el número de la caja
    :return: Una lista con los 9 elementos dentro de la caja
    """
    lista = []
    #   Calcular la fila y columna de la esquina
    #   superior izquierda de la caja.
    fila = 3 * (numero // 3)
    columna = 3 * (numero % 3)
    #   Extraer los 9 digitos de la caja y
    #   ponerlos en una lista.
    for row in range(fila, fila + 3):
        lista.extend(sudoku[row][columna:columna + 3])
    return lista
```

Habiendo extraído los 9 dígitos, podemos comprobar que estén todos convirtiendo la lista en un `set` y contando sus elementos: si contiene nueve elementos, entonces están todos los dígitos:

```
def revisar9(lista):
    """
    Revisa que la lista contenga los digitos 1-9
    sin faltar.
    :param lista: Una lista de 9 enteros
    :return: True si la lista contiene todos los
    digitos de 1 a 9.
    """
    return len(set(lista)) == 9
```

**Demo**

Para facilitarnos la vida, ingresamos el problema como una cadena de 81 dígitos y usamos la función `str_sudoku` para convertirla en una lista de listas.

```
problema = "435269781" \
           "682571493" \
           "197834562" \
           "826195347" \
           "374682915" \
           "951743628" \
           "519326874" \
           "248957136" \
           "763418259"


def str_sudoku(problema):
    """
    Convierte un problema en formato cadena a matriz
    :param problema: Una cadena de 81 digitos.
    :return: Una matriz (lista de listas)
    """
    matriz = []
    for fila in range(9):
        matriz.append(list(problema[fila * 9: (fila + 1) * 9]))
    return matriz


def print_sudoku(sudoku):
    """
    Imprime un sudoku
    :param sudoku: La matriz (lista de listas)
    """
    for fila in sudoku:
        for columna in fila:
            print(columna, end=" ")
        print()
    print()


def revisar9(lista):
    """
    Revisa que la lista contenga los digitos 1-9
    sin faltar.
    :param lista: Una lista de 9 enteros
    :return: True si la lista contiene todos los
    digitos de 1 a 9.
    """
    return len(set(lista)) == 9


def extraer_caja(sudoku, numero):
    """
    Extrae la caja y la convierte en lista
    :param sudoku: La matriz (lista de listas)
    :param numero: 0, 1, 2, ... 8, el número de la caja
    :return: Una lista con los 9 elementos dentro de la caja
    """
    lista = []
    #   Calcular la fila y columna de la esquina
    #   superior izquierda de la caja.
    fila = 3 * (numero // 3)
    columna = 3 * (numero % 3)
    #   Extraer los 9 digitos de la caja y
    #   ponerlos en una lista.
    for row in range(fila, fila + 3):
        lista.extend(sudoku[row][columna:columna + 3])
    return lista


def revisar(sudoku):
    """
    Revisa la corrección de la solución

    :param sudoku: La matriz (lista de listas)
    :return: True si el sudoku está bien resuelto
    """
    #   Revisar por filas.
    for fila in sudoku:
        if not revisar9(fila):
            return False
    #   Revisar por columnas
    for columna in range(9):
        col = []
        #   Reunir los digitos en la columna
        for fila in range(9):
            col.append(sudoku[fila][columna])
        #   Revisar los digitos.
        if not revisar9(col):
            return False
    #   Revisar por cajas
    for caja in range(9):
        #   Extraer los digitos de la caja
        box = extraer_caja(sudoku, caja)
        #   Revisar los digitos.
        if not revisar9(box):
            return False
    #   A estas alturas, la solución es correcta.
    return True


sudoku = str_sudoku(problema)
print_sudoku(sudoku)
if (revisar(sudoku)):
    print("Correcto")
else:
    print("Incorrecto")
```

produce:

```
4 3 5 2 6 9 7 8 1 
6 8 2 5 7 1 4 9 3 
1 9 7 8 3 4 5 6 2 
8 2 6 1 9 5 3 4 7 
3 7 4 6 8 2 9 1 5 
9 5 1 7 4 3 6 2 8 
5 1 9 3 2 6 8 7 4 
2 4 8 9 5 7 1 3 6 
7 6 3 4 1 8 2 5 9 

Correcto
```

Probemos cambiando sólo el primer digito en el mismo problema:

```
3 3 5 2 6 9 7 8 1 
6 8 2 5 7 1 4 9 3 
1 9 7 8 3 4 5 6 2 
8 2 6 1 9 5 3 4 7 
3 7 4 6 8 2 9 1 5 
9 5 1 7 4 3 6 2 8 
5 1 9 3 2 6 8 7 4 
2 4 8 9 5 7 1 3 6 
7 6 3 4 1 8 2 5 9 

Incorrecto
```

Comment: Una duda, en el caso de que hubiesen introducido un cero en el sudoku, también podría salir como correcto, no?

Comment: @AdriánSanzWallace. Correcto. Sólo cuenta los dígitos/caracteres distintos en la matriz. Se parte de la base que la matriz ha sido válidamente llenada con dígitos del 1 al 9. No agregue validación para no agrandar más el código.

Comment: Si, me lo había imaginado, pero me parecía oportuno comentarlo por si no lo había tenido en cuenta @gedauwu

Answer (score 4):

No he podido resistirme a escribir una respuesta usando `numpy` para que pueda observarse su belleza:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain, product

sudoku = np.array([int(c) for c in problema]).reshape((9,9))

def verify(numeros):
  return set(numeros.flatten()) == set(range(1,10))

def cuadrantes(sudoku):
  for y,x in product((0,3,6), (0,3,6)):
    yield sudoku[y:y+3, x:x+3]

def sudoku_ok(sudoku):
  for elemento in chain(sudoku, sudoku.T, cuadrantes(sudoku)):
    if not verify(elemento):
      return False
  return True

print(sudoku)
print(sudoku_ok(sudoku))
```

---

```
[[4 3 5 2 6 9 7 8 1]
 [6 8 2 5 7 1 4 9 3]
 [1 9 7 8 3 4 5 6 2]
 [8 2 6 1 9 5 3 4 7]
 [3 7 4 6 8 2 9 1 5]
 [9 5 1 7 4 3 6 2 8]
 [5 1 9 3 2 6 8 7 4]
 [2 4 8 9 5 7 1 3 6]
 [7 6 3 4 1 8 2 5 9]]
True
```

### Explicación

En numpy se tienen "verdaderos" arrays bidimensionales, en el sentido de que se admite la sintaxis `sudoku[0,0]` por ejemplo, en lugar de `sudoku[0][0]` para acceder a un elemento. Pero lo bueno es que esa nueva sintaxis es usable con rangos, de modo que puedo seleccionar una sub-matriz con algo como: `sudoku[3:6, 3:6]` por ejemplo, para obtener el cuadrante central. Esta es la clave de mi implementación.

#### Detalles

La creación del sudoku a verificar parte de una cadena de texto `problema` que he tomado de la respuesta de @CandidMoe. Esa cadena se convierte en un array numpy haciendo `np.array([int(c) for c in problema])`. No obstante el resultado no es un array bidimensional, sino un vector de 81 elementos, "en linea".

Basta un `.reshape((9,9))` para dejarlo ya en forma de matriz bidimensional de 9x9. Una vez lo tenemos en esta forma:

- El acceso a una fila es simple:  `sudoku[0]` por ejemplo. También sería válida la sintaxis `sudoku[0, :]` pero es redundante en este caso. Iterar por `sudoku` sin más nos devolvería una fila de cada vez.
- El acceso a una columna puede hacerse con la sintaxis `sudoku[:,0]` por ejemplo. El rango `:` significa "todos los elementos", de la columna 0 en este caso.

  No obstante esta sintaxis es farragosa. Resulta más simple hacer `sudoku.T` para obtener la matriz transpuesta, y entonces ya podremos iterar sobre ella para obtener sus filas, que serían las columnas de la matriz original.
- El acceso a un "cuadrante" cualquiera del sudoku se haría con `sudoku[x:x+3, y:y+3]`, dando a `x` y a `y` valores adecuados como por ejemplo 0, 3 ó 6.

  Para obtener uno a uno todos los cuadrantes he escrito el generador `cuadrantes()` que itera sobre todas las parejas posibles de `x` e `y`, para `x` tomando valores en (0,3,6) e `y` lo mismo, gracias a `itertools.product`. Para cada una de esas parejas se retorna el cuadrante correspondiente.

La función `verificar(numeros)` es muy genérica. Recibe como parámetro un array numpy que tanto puede ser una fila, como una columna como un cuadrante. Su "geometría" cambia según lo que sea, ya que si es una fila se tendría un vector de 9 elementos (y si es una columna lo mismo), pero si es un cuadrante será una matriz de 3x3. Para que esta "geometría" no sea importante, se aplica `.flatten()` que deja todo en un vector de 9 elementos. Ese vector se convierte en un conjunto para verificar que los 9 elementos sean diferentes. La función retorna `True` si el conjunto está formado por las cifras 1 a 9 y `False` si no.

Finalmente la función `sudoku_ok` se limita a iterar por todos los "elementos" que deben ser verificados. Esto es, todas las filas, todas las columnas y todos los cuadrantes. Hago uso de `itertools.chain()` para encadenar esos tres iterables: `sudoku` (que irá dando las filas), `sudoku.T` (que irá dando las columnas) y `cuadrantes(sudoku)` (que irá dando los cuadrantes). Cada elemento es verificado y tan pronto como uno produzca `False`, la función retorna `False`. Sólo si todos han pasado retorna `True`.